# Login script doesn't run when logging in through "remote desktop"

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, login-script

I have a Windows 2008 machine (not in a domain) and a user with a "login script" under the profile tab in the user properties to run a batch file.

Supposedly that file must be run when the user logs in but nothing happens when logging in to "Remote Desktop".

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the script with GPO and test with GPMC.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting the logon script on gpedit for all users, and then in the batch file verifying the username to run the script.